# swapping order of differentiation

Tags: partial-derivative

As $r$ is given, I calculate some derivatives using Wolfram Alpha:

$$r=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{x-a}{r}$$
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial a}=-\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{(x-a)^2}{r^3}$$

This equality

$$\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial a^2}=-\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2}$$

I try to prove it myself

$$\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial a^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial r}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial }{\partial a}(-\frac{\partial r}{\partial x})=-\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial a}=-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(-\frac{\partial r}{\partial x})=\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2}$$

Obviously this proof is incorrect. Where I made a mistake? Can't see

Answer (score 1):

This is because what you were trying to prove is wrong. It is actually true that $$\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial a^2}=\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2},$$ which is the result of your (correct) proof.

Comment: No way man; wolframAlpha gives me this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+by+a+((x-a)%2Fsqrt((x-a)%5E2%2B(y-b)%5E2)) . Also I get  this result myself when performing straight-forward differentiation

Comment: But we are talking about the second derivative here...

Comment: What you see there is the first derivative of the first derivative. Which makes it the second derivative

Comment: Ok, did not see that. But still, you will get the same result for the other derivative.

Comment: ok, I see my mistake now and you sir are corrent